# C# GetName() , GetArea() for custom Interface “IShape” and it's derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a task :

There is an hierarchy: "Shape" - interface, "Triangle", "Circle", "Rectangle" - derived classes of "Shape", "IsoscelesTriangle" - derived class of "Triangle", "Square" - derived class of "Rectangle". "Shape" has methods: GetArea() - returns the area of a geometric shape, GetName() - returns the name of a geometric shape. For each derived class area and name can be determined. Console program demonstrates the principle of polymorphism using the output messages of name and area.

My main looks lie this:

```
try {
  Problem1_2.IShape triangle2 = new Problem1_2.Triangle("triangle", 5, 10);
  double triangle2Area = triangle2.GetArea();
  string triangle2Name = triangle2.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine($"Name={triangle2Name}, Area={triangle2Area}");

  Problem1_2.IShape isoTriangle2 = new Problem1_2.IsoscelesTriangle("isosceles triangle", 2, 10);
  double isoTriangle2Area = isoTriangle2.GetArea();
  string isoTriangle2Name = isoTriangle2.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine($"Name={isoTriangle2Name}, Area={isoTriangle2Area}");

  Problem1_2.IShape circle2 = new Problem1_2.Circle("circle", 5);
  double circle2Area = circle2.GetArea();
  string circle2Name = circle2.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine($"Name={circle2Name}, Area={circle2Area}");

  Problem1_2.IShape rect2 = new Problem1_2.Rectangle("rectangle", 2, 10);
  double rect2Area = rect2.GetArea();
  string rect2Name = rect2.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine($"Name={rect2Name}, Area={rect2Area}");

  Problem1_2.IShape square2 = new Problem1_2.Square("square", 2);
  double square2Area = square2.GetArea();
  string square2Name = square2.GetName();
  Console.WriteLine($"Name={square2Name}, Area={square2Area}");
} catch (Exception) {
  Console.WriteLine("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
}
```

my custom classes namespace looks like this:

```
interface IShape
{
    string GetName();
    double GetArea();
}

public class Triangle : IShape
{
    protected double side;
    protected double height;
    protected string name;

    public Triangle(string name, double side, double height)
    {
        if (side >= 0 && height >= 0)
        {
            this.side = side;
            this.height = height;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
        }
    }

    protected Triangle(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "Shape: " + Name;
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        double area = (side * height) / 2;
        return area;
    }
}

public class Circle : IShape
{
    private double radius;

    public Circle(string name, double radius)
    {
        if (radius >= 0)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
        }
    }
    protected Circle(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "Shape: " + Name;
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
        return area;
    }
}

public class Rectangle : IShape
{
    protected double side1;
    protected double side2;

    public Rectangle(string name, double side1, double side2)
    {
        if (side1 >= 0 && side2 >= 0)
        {
            this.side1 = side1;
            this.side2 = side2;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
        }
    }

    protected Rectangle(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "Shape: " + Name;
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        double area = side1 * side2;
        return area;
    }
}

public class IsoscelesTriangle : Triangle
{
    public IsoscelesTriangle(string name, double side, double height) : base(name, side, height) { }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return base.GetArea();
    }
}

public class Square : Rectangle
{
    private double side1;

    public Square(string name, double side1) : base(name, side1, side1)
    {
        if (side1 >= 0)
        {
            this.side1 = side1;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
        }
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        double area = side1 * side1;
        return area;
    }
}
```

But for some reason my classes names gets "null" instead of name. and returns only  "Shape: " instead of:

```
return "Shape: " + Name;
```

can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: Only one of your constructors assigns a value to the `Name` property.  The other one (which you are using in your main code) leaves it with the default value of null.

Comment: i tried that only to try. but still even in that one it doesn't work.   returns only "Shape: "

Comment: @MaxSkliar i was addressed your code problem in my post down, hope it helps

Comment: It is not clear what precisely the goal is here. The comment above by @BJ is spot-on, but how best to address it is unclear. If you want the caller to provide the name, you can use `: this(name)` in the three-parameter constructor declaration to pass the value to the single-parameter constructor and have the property value set. IMHO, better would be to have a base class that implements the `Name` property and has the constructor; then you'd use `: base(name)` instead. But if the names are specific to each type, why let the caller provide it at all? Why not just hard-code the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
protected Triangle(string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
public string Name { get; }

public virtual string GetName()
{
    return "Shape: " + Name;
}
```

to:

```
const string Name = "Triangle";

public virtual string GetName()
{
    return "Shape: " + Name;
}
```

(and much the same for Circle etc)

Your old code allowed the name to be passed in, which is unnecessary. Think about them as people - you don't *tell* someone their name, you *ask* them. Thus, the class is in the best position to know its own name - so a constant there is best.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating different kind of shapes, you are calling the base class constructor using `base()` and passing the proper parameters, but in the constructor definitions you are not setting the `Name` property, you need to set that or you can call the constructor which sets the `Name` property, for example:

```
public Triangle(string name, double side, double height)
{
    Name = name; // note this
    if (side >= 0 && height >= 0)
    {
        this.side = side;
        this.height = height;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
    }
}
```

or more better would be to use `this()` to call the constructor which is setting the `Name` property as well which can be done like (as you have constructor available which sets the `Name` of a particular `IShape` instance):

```
public Triangle(string name, double side, double height) : this(name)
{

    ........
    ........
    ........
}
```

The same way you need to call the proper constructor of `Circle` as well which would set the `Name` property as well :

```
public Circle(string name, double radius) : this(name) // call the constrcutor which takes Name
{
    if (radius >= 0)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
    }
}
```

and lastly do it for the `Rectangle` class as well:

```
public Rectangle(string name, double side1, double side2) : this(name)
{
    ........
    ........
    ........
}
```

The line `this(name)` will cause the constructor of `Rectangle` , `Circle` etc single parameter constructor to be called which is setting the `Name` property for the object which is getting instantiated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What would happen if I called `new Circle("Rectangle", 15)`? What would it report the shape as?

Comment: it will return **"Rectangle"** in the `Name` property, but the object will be of type `Cricle`

Comment: @mjwills that is not the point here of OP, OP is trying to grasp the OOP concept using an exercise i.e. understanding of Polymorphism

Comment: good thought. but i think that the better way is not to set up a Name from main. And just return a const name of shape. but thx for looking into my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Triangle` class which implements the `IShape` interface. This mean the class must implement the `GetName` and `GetArea` methods. The `Triangle` class has properties of `side1`, `height` and `name`.

The “first” constructor takes the string, name, side and height variable, checks the side and height for greater than zero then sets the properties for those variables. PROBLEM: the `name` variable never gets set in this constructor. Below this appears to be another constructor for this…, which is unnecessary. Simply set the `name` in the original constructor, as you should be doing anyway. So, you can get rid of the `protected Triangle(string name)` constructor, along with the `Name` getter. All you need are the two methods for the `IShape` interface. Triangle class below:

```
public class Triangle : IShape {
  protected double side;
  protected double height;
  protected string Name;

  public Triangle(string name, double side, double height) {
    if (side >= 0 && height >= 0) {
      this.side = side;
      this.height = height;
      Name = name;
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Critical error: Value cannot be negative");
    }
  }

  public string GetName() {
    return Name;
  }

  public double GetArea() {
    double area = (side * height) / 2;
    return area;
  }
}
```

Moving on to the `Circle`, and `Rectangle` classes you can see the same problems: name is not set in the original constructor. Similar changes as above should fix this. Moving on to the other two classes `IsoscelesTriangle` which inherits from the `Trangle` class and `Square` which inherits from the `Rectangle` class.. In these classes you need to keep in mind that since you are inheriting from the other classes… they hold most of the variables we need, so we only need to initialize the base, then implement the `GetArea()` method if different. Since the `GetArea` methods are the same as the base… there is no need to implement them as the base already implements them. If they are different, then you would override the `GetArea` method for that class.

```
public class IsoscelesTriangle : Triangle {

  public IsoscelesTriangle(string name, double side, double height) : base(name, side, height) { }

 }

public class Square : Rectangle {

  public Square(string name, double side1) : base(name, side1, side1) { }

}
```

Hope this makes sense.